# libvirt and virt-manager - Unable to complete install: 'internal error: unsupported input bus usb'

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, libvirt, virt-manager

I'm following the steps below to create a virtual machine using Xen as hypervisor and virt-manager (libvirt) as the management module. When trying to create the virtual machine I am getting the following error:

> Unable to complete install: 'internal error: unsupported input bus
>   usb'

**ERROR DETAILS:**

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: unsupported input bus usb'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 75, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 2276, in _do_async_install
    guest.start_install(meter=meter)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 461, in start_install
    doboot, transient)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/guest.py", line 397, in _create_guest
    domain = self.conn.createXML(install_xml or final_xml, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 3717, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: unsupported input bus usb
```

**NOTE I:** The deploy process follows the instructions here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwkmDM-Gpzc and here https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart .
**NOTE II:** Xen Hypervisor uses a CentOS 7 as "domu".

---

**STEPS:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my version and the problem no longer occurred!

Here's what Cole Robinson replied to me on the "libvirt-users" mailing list (libvirt-users@redhat.com):

```
Coincidentally this a bug I fixed just this morning:

commit b1eb07c26aae1b303cd9893427f46f5b693544b3 (HEAD -> master, 
origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Cole Robinson <crobinso@redhat.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 22 08:38:33 2018 -0400

     guest: Don't add usb tablet for xen PV

     xen PV doesn't have USB support


But you can work around it: at the end of the 'new vm' wizard, click 
'customize before install', and in the VM details window, remove the 
tablet device, then finish the install. That should make things work
```

Thank you! =D

**NOTE:** https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/master/INSTALL.md